# How to implement RelativeMove with buttons to an IP Camera (ONVIF)

Tags: c#, ip-camera, onvif

Can somebody tell me why the Up and Down case works perfectly with the buttons and the others dont? I tried with those 2 different ways, one you see in the left case and one in the right case, but both dont work at all.

```
 void Move(String direction)
        {
            timer.Enabled = true;
            switch (direction)
            {
                case "Up ":

                    onvifPTZ.RelativeMove(0, 1f, 0, (float)Pan_Speed.Value, (float)Tilt_Speed.Value, (float)Zoom_Speed.Value);
                    break;
                case "Down":
                    onvifPTZ.RelativeMove(0, -1f, 0, (float)Pan_Speed.Value, (float)Tilt_Speed.Value, (float)Zoom_Speed.Value);
                    break;
                case "Left":
                    direction = Direction.Left.ToString();
                    onvifPTZ.RelativeMove((float)Direction.Left, 0, 0, (float)Pan_Speed.Value, (float)Tilt_Speed.Value, (float)Zoom_Speed.Value);
                    break;
                case "Right":

                    onvifPTZ.RelativeMove(-1f, 0, 0, (float)Pan_Speed.Value, (float)Tilt_Speed.Value, (float)Zoom_Speed.Value);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

This is my relative Move function btw.

```
 public int RelativeMove(float xTrans, float yTrans, float zTrans, float xSpeed , float ySpeed, float zSpeed)
        {
            // Define Translation Vector
            PTZ.PTZVector ptzTrans = new PTZ.PTZVector()
            {
                PanTilt = new PTZ.Vector2D()
                {
                    x = xTrans,
                    y = yTrans,
                    space = ptzOptions.Spaces.RelativePanTiltTranslationSpace[0].URI,
                },
                Zoom = new PTZ.Vector1D()
                {
                    x = zTrans,
                    //space = ptzOptions.Spaces.RelativeZoomTranslationSpace[0].URI,
                }
            };
            // Define Speed Vector
            PTZ.PTZSpeed ptzSpd = new PTZ.PTZSpeed()
            {
                PanTilt = new PTZ.Vector2D()
                {
                    x = xSpeed,
                    y = ySpeed,
                    //space = ptzOptions.Spaces.RelativePanTiltTranslationSpace[0].URI,
                },
                Zoom = new PTZ.Vector1D()
                {
                    x = zSpeed,
                   // space = ptzOptions.Spaces.RelativeZoomTranslationSpace[0].URI,
                }
            };

            // Move relative along vectore <ptzTrans> with speed <ptzSpd> 
            // Zoom is manipulated with <zSpeed>.
            ptzClient.RelativeMove(profiles[this.selectedProfile].token, ptzTrans, ptzSpd);

            return 0;
        }
```

If somebody has an idea how i could do it so it works, please help :) and if somebody knows how to stop the movement when i dont press the button tell me, cause it also dont works...I did implement it and tell the camera to stop the movement in there, but it doesnt react at all.

Comment: Btw the speeds work perfectly, its only the move direction that i need to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I understand that you are trying to move the PTZ unit by using speed. This does not match however the function `RelativeMove` that you are using in the code.

From the [ONVIF PTZ specs](https://www.onvif.org/specs/srv/ptz/ONVIF-PTZ-Service-Spec-v1712.pdf):

> If  a  PTZ  node  supports  relative  Pan/Tilt  or  relative  Zoom 
>   movements,  then  it  shall support the RelativeMove operation. The
>   translation argument of this operation specifies the difference from
>   the current position to the position to which the PTZ device is
>   instructed to move. The operation is split into an optional Pan/Tilt
>   element and an optional Zoom element. If the Pan/Tilt element is
>   omitted, the current Pan/Tilt movement shall NOT be affected by this
>   command. The same holds for the zoom element.

Therefore, you have two options:

- Verify whether `ContinuousMove` is the function that does what you are looking for
- If you really want to use `RelativeMove`, check what `ptzOptions.Spaces.RelativePanTiltTranslationSpace[0].URI` is. It may be a custom space with different ranges for pan and tilt.